# how to remove HTML tags from a string in JavaScript without using regexp?

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and I was solving this exercise.
I have tried 3 loops with string.slice() but for some reason it prints an empty string.

Would you please explain what happens inside my code and why it prints the wrong output and how I can correct, rather than giving me your version of the correct answer, so that I can learn from my mistakes.

the test input is

```
<p><strong><em>PHP Exercises</em></strong></p>
```

and output should be PHP Exercises

p.s this is not a PHP exercise, I'm not confused

here is my code :

```
function remove(answer){ 

    var sen = answer.split("");
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i<answer.length; i++){
        if (answer[i] == "<"){
            for (var j = i; j<answer.length; j++){
                if (answer[j] == ">"){
                    for (var k = j; k<answer.length; k++){
                        if (answer[k] == "<"){
                            return answer.slice(j+1, k);                
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this is not going to be easy and very likely very messy and buggy in the end. Why no regex? It would make your life so much easier...

Comment: @Lucero No, regexp would not make his/her life easier. Parsing HTML with regexp is broken.

Comment: I haven't learnt RegEX yet, scheduled for next week, I just thought I'd challenge myself (enthusiasm of newbies :D)

Comment: It's looking for a <, then a > then another < ... which is satisfied by the first four characters of your string ("<p><").  It then returns everything between the > and the 2nd <, which is a zero length string.

Comment: @Tibrogargan yea but I used loops so that the function keeps doing that until no more <,> followed by another < are to be found

Comment: @naomik Parsing with regex only is broken, removing tags not... Because using regex to identify single tags is completely fine, just not matching tag pairs in one regex due to nesting.

Comment: No, it returns the first time it finds a second <

Comment: @Tibrogargan yea but how can I edit the code to keep the loop running ? any idea?

Comment: @Lucero `<div data-nope="> you failed">go for it</div>`

Comment: Without using num8er's awesome solution, you probably want to look for the first thing that follows a '>' that isn't a '<' or whitespace and keep a record of the index, that's the start of your string.  Rest is up to you :)  (Or, only return if what you slice from the string is not zero length)

Comment: @Mohamed Hegazy Your condition can be fit in "<tag1><tag2", the "<" before tag2

Comment: @naomik First if it is HTML you should not have a literal `<` or `>` in the attribute value (but rather `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Anyways, a simple regex like this works just fine: `<([^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')+>` That being said, pretty much every parser (for any text format including HTML or XML) uses a tokenizer with some form of regex to identify tokens, and then run that through some some LALR, LR or LL parser algorithm.

Comment: @Lucero sure, I'll properly encode the values in my data attributes, but you can't depend on your inputs doing that 100% of the time. I understand that parsers utilize regexp to perform tasks, but a single regexp alone cannot reliably extract this value. I'm not going into this any further. This is an tired, old argument. Everyone in the "just use regexp" camp is wrong and I'm not sorry.

Comment: @naomik As I said before, using regex as parser for HTML does not work due to the missing recursion capabilities (in fact it does work with the .NET regex flavor with balanced groups but that's too complicated for you). This I can agree. Identifying *single* tags (not pairs!) is a completely valid application of regex ant not broken at all. That's where you are just wrong.

Comment: @Lucero btw, [the only character not allowed in an html attribute value contained within `"` is another `"`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-attributes). `<div data-nope="> you failed">go for it</div>` is completely valid.

Comment: @naomik Sure, and my example regex does just that! Still the recommendation is to actually escape them - and I wrote "should", not "must" in my comment: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#use "There are three characters that **should** always appear in content as escapes..."

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```js
function stripTags(data)
{
   var tmpElement = document.createElement("div");
   tmpElement.innerHTML = data;
   return tmpElement.textContent || tmpElement.innerText || "";
}

var something = '<p><strong><em>PHP Exercises</em></strong></p>';
alert(stripTags(something));
```

or You can use string.js ([string.js link](http://stringjs.com/#methods/striptags-tag1-tag2)):

```js
var S = window.S;
var something = '<p><strong><em>PHP Exercises</em></strong></p>';
something = S(something).stripTags().s;
alert(something);
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jprichardson/string.js/master/dist/string.min.js"></script>
```

if You're trying nodejs so:

```
var S = require('string');
var something = '<p><strong><em>PHP Exercises</em></strong></p>';
something = S(something).stripTags().s;
console.log(something);
```

Comment: The assumption that it's running in a DOM Document may be flawed, but it's good anyway :)

Comment: A+ nice answer. I was unaware that `.textContent` would work even for nested children. I was in the middle of writing up an answer that recursively reduced children using `.textContent` on the entire tree. This is obviously much simpler.

Comment: It's the only way to do it properly. This is the correct answer so long as the html is correctly formatted.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Yes, correct, the question of newbie is about how to work with clientside JS. But in case of nodejs, I'll use cheerio - simple, beautiful package.

Comment: @num8er he never mentions client side anything, just Javascript.  He could be working in any number of Javascript engines (but almost certainly isn't, lol)

Comment: @num8er Thanks alot for your answer I'm assuming it's a great answer from reading the comments, I just find it hard to understand some statements like .createElement, .innerHTML, .textcontent, .innerText, but I'll try and google it.

Comment: @Tibrogargan, also I've added example with string.js package. ;)

Comment: @Tibrogargan yes certainly I'm not working on any engines lol, I just statrted learning programming recently :)

Comment: @MohamedHegazy This solution is basically leveraging the (assumed) browser's functionality for converting a string into a document object model (DOM), which has properties (like `innerText`) exposing the data in an easy-to use format. This doesn't teach you anything about parsing text though, but it would be a safe and clean solution for solving a real-world problem.

Comment: @Mohamed Hegazy A JavaScript engine is a component that runs JavaScript.  Web Browsers use them to run JavaScript, but there's a lot of other places where they can be useful.  "Server side" JavaScript perhaps being the most common outside browsers,  Your teachers could be evil and be forcing you to use a plain vanilla engine (that doesn't do fancy DOM tricks)

Comment: Thanks alot for your explanation

Answer (score 1):

As to why the provided code isn't working, the code returns when j = 2 and k = 3. I discovered this by writing console.log(j, k); immediately before the return. This insight made it clear that the code is identifying the first set of open tags, when actually you seem to want to identify the open and closed "em" tags. The answers provided by others are more robust, but a quick fix to your code is:

change

```
if (answer[i] == "<"){
```

to

```
if (answer.slice(i, i+3) == "<em"){
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

Your code does not account for ... *nothing*. It simply stops at the first encounter of what's between ">" and "<", which is, in the first case, is nothing! You should check if a character is present, and move on if not.

Honestly, this is one of those useless exercises that text books use to try to get you to think outside the box. But you will never want to loop through a string to find text between tags. There are so many methods built in to JavaScript, it's literally reinventing the wheel to do this... that is if a wheel were really a for-loop.

If you really want to avoid Regex and other built in functions so that you can learn to problem solve the long way, well try slicing by brackets first!

Comment: I figure you're one of them anti-textbook programmers lol, nothing wrong with that though, I was actually solving w3resource exercise as I'm also anti-textbook exercises :) thanks for your advice mate

Comment: I'm definitely not anti-textbook haha I'm just anti-useless-workarounds... Programming should be learned just like math-- learning simpler techniques and building on those to more complex ones. You should never have to learn to do something in a way that is impractical if you will soon replace it with a more practical way anyway. It's like learning to change a tire by using a stick and a log because you haven't learned to use a jack.